# Awful PyCharm Community Edition Kerning

Tags: fonts, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, kerning

I recently installed the latest version of PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3, and the font kerning is now excruciatingly bad.

I can't seem to find any options to control this, can anyone explain how to make it so my capital letters don't all overlap?

[image: Bad Font Kerning]

Comment: Will it be any better if you tick `Enable font ligatures` option? I'm thinking in the lines of this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158410#comment=27-1514729

Comment: Enabling ligatures makes the kerning wider (worse) between letters that are unaffected, and doesn't have any affect on the ones which are overlapping. See http://imgur.com/a/Vm7Mv

Comment: Contacted support and they suggested I install a different Java JDK. I did so using homebrew, then looked for the option "Switch IDE Boot JDK" and changed it to the newly installed version, fixing my problem.